# Matrix strategy over entire workflow in github actions

Tags: github-actions

With the matrix strategy and two jobs like those below, the first job runs a "matrix" of possible configurations in parallel, and when all of them succeed, it moves onto the second job.

```yaml
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        version: [10, 12, 14]
    steps:
      # etc

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job1
    strategy:
      matrix:
        version: [10, 12, 14]
    steps:
      # etc
```

What would be nice is to essentially have a matrix over the whole workflow, where for each matrix value, the entire workflow of jobs is run unimpeded, in parallel. That means for a particular configuration `job2` can proceed right after `job1` completes for that configuration, regardless of whether `job1` for another configuration is still in process or has failed.

In the following diagram, the first case is what will currently happen, and the second is the desired case:

[image: diagram of github actions matrix]

I feel like this could be "emulated" by launching the workflow several times with a different context. But how could this be done, for example from a trigger? Somehow specify `on: push` that 3 versions of the workflow must run simultaneously?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that job2 would be in a separate workflow without matrix but instead accepting version as an input. Each job1 variant would then trigger this workflow with its own version as the input at the end of its run. Obviously, this far from being as nice as having it all in one workflow.

Comment: @tmt Thanks for the suggestion. We settled on using reusable workflows, but you can have a matrix that calls an entire other workflow that has all the jobs in it. See my answer below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some digging, I think "Reusable workflows" is the currently supported method.

The solution is to have two workflow files. One that has all the jobs, and another small workflow that has the matrix and calls the other workflow.

```yaml
name: Common Workflow

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      version: # the variable you can use in place of a matrix
        required: true
        type: number

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo 'job1 version ${{ inputs.version }}'

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job1
    steps:
      - run: echo 'job2 version ${{ inputs.version }}'
```

```yaml
name: Master Workflow

on:
  push:

jobs:
  version-matrix:
    strategy:
      # super important if you want to see all results, even if one fails
      # fail-fast is true by default
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        version: [10, 12, 14]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/common-workflow.yml # calls the one above ^
    with:
      version: ${{ matrix.version }}
    secrets: inherit
```

Here's a real example of it running in the UI:

[image: Reusable Workflows UI lists jobs in alphabetical order]

One thing you will run into once you run this though, is the UI lists the subjobs in alphabetical order, and not the order they are listed in the workflow. So you lose the sense of the dependencies between the jobs. This is true in February 2023, so maybe Github will improve the UI down the road. Until then, we got around this by naming our jobs like `1. First Job`, `2. Second Job` so alphabetical is equivalent to the order they run in. It's hacky but it works.

Another thing to note, especially for deployments is the `fail-fast` attribute. This should be set to `false` to make sure every workflow in the matrix gets to run to completion, even if one of them fails.

Comment: As of May 31st 2023, the UI issue is still intact, although for me the sub-jobs aren't necessarily in alphabetical order, but just in a random order in the UI, and the UI tree is just one big jobs list, instead of a real tree that showcases the sub-jobs dependency in each Matrix value